# Get version of the docker base image used to build an image

Tags: docker, containers, virtualization, dockerfile, docker-image

I had built a docker image A, using a base image B. Now I built another new image C, using the latest version of the same base image B, but I notice lot of changes and difference in the new base image B compared with the older version of the base image B I had used earlier. Is there anyway I can get to know the version of the older base image B which I had used to build the docker image A?

Comment: Did you try `docker images`? It will shows your locally downloaded image, assuming you did not delete it nor downloaded newer one when you built C. IMO, it is a better practice to set the whole tag explicitly.

Comment: keep the  base image on your local machine so it will not pull the latest image from docker hub